Duplicating/cloning huggingface space

I'm interested in setting up an inference API, using huggingface. I'm following an article https://medium.com/@dahmanihichem01/mixtral-and-rest-api-turning-mixtral-8x7b-into-an-api-using-huggingface-spaces-a8b150b47246 which shows how to do this.
I've gotten to the point where it says:
"Go to the right top corner and press the three dots button, then click “Clone Repository”

If I understand correctly, this should be enough to set up a cloned space. However currently I see the screenshot.
# Make sure you have git-lfs installed (https://git-lfs.com)
git lfs install

git clone https://huggingface.co/spaces/iiced/mixtral-46.7b-fastapi

# If you want to clone without large files - just their pointers
GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone https://huggingface.co/spaces/iiced/mixtral-46.7b-fastapi

Am I supposed to clone the repository to my local machine and then upload it back to huggingspace , or am I missing something?

I figured it out - when you duplicate the space you need to make it public. Then you can embed it and get a functioning endpoint
